# Remove nib from superview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cllocationmanager

I am simply trying to remove a view from it's superview when a respective button is pressed, but am failing to do so.

The view is a custom nib I created, called `RequestLocationView`

Called from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
func initBeaconServices() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    if locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
        requestView = RequestLocationView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        requestView.setupView()
        requestView.alpha = 0
        requestView.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(requestView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay : 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.requestView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "869A6E2E-AE14-4CF5-8313-8D6976058A7A")

    // Create the beacon region to search for with those values.
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid!, identifier: "com.dejordan.Capiche")
}
```

Here's the code for the `RequestView`:

```
class RequestLocationView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var acceptButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rejectButton: UIButton!

    var lView: UIView!

    weak var delegate: HandleLocationPermissionDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    private func xibSetup() {
        lView = loadViewFromNib()
        lView.frame = bounds
        lView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        lView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(lView)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first

        return nibView as! UIView
    }

    func setupView() {
        acceptButton.layer.cornerRadius = acceptButton.frame.height / 2
    }

    func fadeIn(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.3, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func fadeOut(completion:  ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.3, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    @IBAction func acceptPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.allowPermissions()
    }

    @IBAction func rejecttPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.denyPermissions()
    }
}
```

Here are the delegate methods in the parent viewController:

```
func allowPermissions() {
    requestView.fadeOut {(finished)  in
        if finished {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.requestView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}

func denyPermissions() {
    requestView.fadeOut {(didFinish) in
        self.requestView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

And this is what happens when you click reject... You can see the background slightly fading but that's it, and the view stays where it is.

[image: Not responding as hoped...]

I've been scratching my head for a while on this one, and have scoured many Stack Overflow posts to no avail...

Comment: Have you confirmed that your delegate functions are actually being reached?

Comment: Yup. Threw some logs in `denyPermission` and they consistently are called, even multiple times in succession, thanks for the suggestion though @DonMag!

Comment: Don't know if you'll consider this good news or bad -- I just did a quick test using your code (minus the `CLLocationManager`), and it works as desired... `denyPermissions()` is called on the delegate, view fades out, view is removed from superview. Try commenting out the `CLLocationManager` stuff and see if you get the results you want... if that works, add stuff back in until it fails again.

Comment: hmm strange, moving the initialization into viewDidLoad seems to have done the trick! That solves that problem, however my `acceptButton.layer.cornerRadius = acceptButton.frame.height / 2` isn't working (wasn't working at time of post either). I threw it into viewDidLayoutSubviews to try to fix it to no avail it seems...anyhoo I can create a separate SO question for that, @DonMag feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the `CLLocationManager` code is interacting in a not-so-friendly manner.

If moving the `RequestLocationView` initialization into `viewDidLoad` corrects the issue, that's likely the cause.

To get the proper radius on your `acceptButton`, try adding a `layoutSubviews` handler to your custom view:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    acceptButton.layer.cornerRadius = acceptButton.bounds.height / 2
}
```

Comment: hmmmm tossing `acceptButton.layer.cornerRadius = acceptButton.bounds.height / 2` into `layoutSubviews()` didn't seem to work.... it seems the calculated corner radius is too small

Comment: what's interesting is that it only doesn't work on larger layouts, iPhone 6/7/8 Plus, and iPhone X, all the iPads, whereas it works fine on the other smaller devices.

Comment: @DaneJordan - hmmm... not sure why you're seeing different results. I put my scratch project up if you want to try to compare: https://github.com/DonMag/TmpDJ

Comment: wow! very grateful for all the effort you've expended on my behalf  I think the problem may lie in the fact i'm using stack views in my xib file...

Comment: Unless you're doing something really odd with them, I can't imagine why stack views would affect it... I'll throw those elements in a stack view and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, added the elements to a stack view, and still no problem. I re-synched the GitHub repo if you want to look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157402/discussion-between-dane-jordan-and-donmag).